# List permission at the time of list creation

Tags: 2010, list, permissions

Is it possible to define list permissions at the time of list creation using out of box features in SharePoint 2010?

By default new lists are visible to all users, I don't want them to access newly created lists or libraries.

Comment: For this you need to break permission for all newly crated list.

Comment: well i don't want to go into list permissions and then stop inheritance. At time of list creation itself i want to specify the users.

Comment: You can't. SharePoint can break Inheritance **after** an object is created. Only way to make it more seamless is to create the Lists with code and make the code break inheritance

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve? This may be easier to answer if you explain the bigger picture.

You could
- create a site and a few lists / libraries and allow access to these existing lists via SharePoint groups
- at the site level change all access to "limited"
- edit each existing list/library, break permission inheritance an manually set permissions as desired.

Each newly created list/library will now inherit the unbroken "limited" settings.

Overall, you may want to re-think your access permission strategy.

If you don't want people to access lists/libraries, why create them in the first place.

I feel you need to do some more sophisticated access planning. Put the average user into the Visitors group and don't allow them to see lists/libraries.

Create SharePoint groups for more privileged users and define their permissions on a list/library basis.

Comment: Thanks for the response, In my case we have 100 users for a site collection. Now i want to create a list for three users a, b, c. when i create a list until i edit user permissions and restrict list to a, b, c it will be visible to all the users. i want to create a list and while creating list give permissions to a, b, c at the same time

Comment: You may want to look into Powershell to set up the lists and permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no out of the box way to assign permissions to lists as they are created like you want.

However there is a (hopefully) better way. What I would suggest instead is that you create a sub site for each subset of users that you want to assign to lists. When you create a new sub site, you can create new groups and assign membership to them as you are creating the site. You can then add any lists that only this group should see in to the sub site.

This may seem like more work to set up initially, but as your sites and usage grows it is actually far far easier to control and maintain. If you simply use one site with lots of lists and each with custom permissions, it becomes very difficult to determine who has access to what and to add/remove users from across multiple lists. If you manage it through sub sites and groups, it's much easier to see who is in a group and what that group has access to, and far easier to add/remove people simply by adding/removing them for a much smaller number of groups.